# ST's FOC for BLDC start up errors

Tags: stm32, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, algorithm, pmsm

I am using ST's FOC library 4.3. I am able to run my NovoMotec motor as I want, with the Observer + PLL configuration. Often (1 out of 5) during the start -up period, my motor stops, and I get a start-up failure error. I can not solve this problem, so that my motor would start all time (5 out of 5). I dont know, which parameter should I tune:

1. Speed regulators ( they seem fine, once the motor started)
2. Start-up parameters. ( These should be tuned maybe. ) 
   I thought that since it is a low inductance motor,maybe it should be started so.
3. Drive parameters ( since the motor runs, i dont think it's the problem)

Here are pictures of the wb Start-up parameters:

[image: The parameters of the Start-up sequence]

And the motor parameters:

[image: Motor parameters]

Comment: are you sure your rotor alignment is at 90deg?

Comment: I am not sure. But the datasheet does not say anything about it. How can I be sure? It is a NovoMotec 3570 series motor.

Comment: What the manual says about that kind of error? How is the rotor angle measured or estimated?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, your motor has rotor of uniform shape and have glued permanent magnets. There is a certain problem detecting the rotor position for the sensorless method, as it is takes the advantage of the reluctance paths of the internal PMSM (I-PMSM) which has a "buried" permanent magnet in the stack laminations.

[image]

Your motor is probably SM-SMPM which has surface mounted (glued) magnets (blue) with very little gap.

You would need to ad an encoder feedback, or change the motor with I-PMSM, as the new sensorless method uses the reluctance path of iron core to detect the position/speed.